# Proving $|\sqrt{x}-1|\leqslant|x-1|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

I tried squaring both sides, didn’t get me anywhere. Maybe going case by case would result in something but I think there could be amore elegant proof.

Comment: Do you need to prove the inequality for all $x \ge 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For $x \ge 0$,

$$x-1 = (\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)$$

Try to take absolute value on both sides.

Edit:

$$|x-1| = |\sqrt{x}-1||\sqrt{x}+1| \ge |\sqrt{x}-1|(1)=|\sqrt{x}-1|$$

Comment: taking absolute values here doesn’t change anything right?

Comment: What can you say about the lower bound of $|\sqrt{x}+1|=\sqrt{x}+1$?

Comment: I think it’s zero?

Comment: $0$ is indeed a lower bound but actually we know a little bit more. $\sqrt{x} \ge 0$, what about $\sqrt{x}+1$?

Comment: lower bound of $\sqrt{x}+1$ is 1, so?

Comment: See the edit. we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One last thing, how can I improve my ability, how should I practice?

Comment: Not much advice besides practice more? Also be familiar with some identities like in this question $a^2-b^2$ is used. Don't rush when one learns as well. It takes time to build a good foundation. Learning takes time and different people learn differently.

Answer (score 3):

Note that we have for $x,y>0$
$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| = \frac{|(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}} = \frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}.$$
Thus, taking $y=1$, we find
$$|\sqrt{x}-1| = \frac{|x-1|}{\sqrt{x}+1} \leq |x-1|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\ge 0$:

$|x-1|= |√x-1||√x+1| \ge$

$ |√x-1|\cdot 1 =|√x-1|.$

Used: $|√x+1| \ge 1.$